# iPhone 5s iOS not supported by the version of Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, version, xcode6, ios8.1

I'm trying to upload my app to the store for testing on my iPhone 5s and trying to execute a step: "Adding Launch Images and Capturing Screenshots" mentioned in the link below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW1

More specifically, When I select my iPhone 5s under devices, I see a message "your iPhone may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by Xcode" I have iOS 8.1 (12B411) on my phone and Xcode 6. Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the latest Xcode 6.1 installed? I have experienced the same while i was working through xcode 5 and xcode 6 with my iphone ios 8. Xcode 5 didnt recognize it so the solution was to insert the iphone in xcode 6 and then in xcode 5.

Comment: Yes, it worked after installing the latest copy of Xcode, that is, version 6.1 on mac. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of iOS  version installed on your iphone, if iphone 5s has ios 8.1 than it can not be able to connect with  xcode 6.0